# Как принудительно установить приложение на sd-карту

Tags: android

Всем здравствуйте.
Есть ли в Android способ принудительной установки приложения на sd-карту. Интересует как вариант при скачивании из google play, так и установка .apk-файла. Мало приложений, которые дают возможность средствами Android перенести все данные на sd-карту. Разработчики остальных приложений считают, что такой функции пользователям не нужно. Но память не резиновая. Знает кто-нибудь решение? Только не предлагайте купить новый телефон))

Comment: Вопрос оффтоп, если речь идёт не о приложении, которое разрабатываете **вы**. Разработчики приложений не считают, что перенос на карту не нужен - проблема в том, что разработчики ОС не гарантируют перенесённым приложениям некоторый функционал.

Comment: Не знал, извините, буду тогда продолжать искать на просторах нета. Спасибо за уделенное время.)

Comment: Ещё остались телефоны которым нужна SD карта??